# React: I believe I have a GOTCHA for a double async fetch call. I click the button once part of the setState renders I click again and then it renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Question:

I am developing a small app that is a memory game of Formula One Drivers to practice React. It makes a call to an API to get the driver info then I have to make a second API call to Wikipedia to get the driver images. When I submit the year and click the button it will only load half the information **Image 1** & **getDrivers function**. When I click the button again it will load the images **Image 2** & **getDriversImgs function / retrievingImgUrl**.

I believe I am encountering a GOTCHA or doing something fundamentally wrong. I am not sure in my setDrivers call in the retrievingImgUrl() function if it isn't updating because it is a reference to an array even though I use map and it should be returning a new array?

Or is this something where I need to use useEffect or useCallback to have the code rerender in one go?

Any advice on how to fix the bug and if you could point me in a direction to possibly clean up these fetch calls or would you consider this clean code (like conceptually chaining fetch calls together in smaller functions or should I make it one big function)?

```
import { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";

// Components
import Header from "./components/header/Header";
import CardList from "./components/main/CardList";
import Modal from "./components/UI/Modal";

// CSS
import classes from "./App.module.css";

function App() {
  const [drivers, setDrivers] = useState([]);

  const getDrivers = async (year) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://ergast.com/api/f1/" + year + "/drivers.json"
    );
    const data = await response.json();

    let driverInfo = [];
    data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers.map((driver) => {
      driverInfo.push({
        id: driver.code,
        firstName: driver.givenName,
        lastName: driver.familyName,
        wikipedia: driver.url,
        image: null,
      });
    });
    setDrivers(driverInfo);
    getDriversImgs();
  };

  async function getDriversImgs() {
    console.log(drivers);
    const responses = await Promise.all(
      drivers.map((driver) => {
        let wikiPageName = driver.wikipedia.split("/").slice(-1).toString();
        let wiki_url =
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=query&titles=" +
          wikiPageName +
          "&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500";
        return fetch(wiki_url);
      })
    );
    const urls = await Promise.all(responses.map((r) => r.json())).then(
      (json) => retrievingImgUrl(json)
    );
    setDrivers((prev) => {
      return prev.map((item, idx) => {
        return { ...item, image: urls[idx] };
      });
    });
  }

  const retrievingImgUrl = async (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    const strippingData = data.map((d) => {
      return d.query.pages;
    });
    const urls = strippingData.map((d) => {
      const k = Object.keys(d)[0];
      try {
        return d[k].thumbnail.source;
      } catch {
        return null;
      }
    });
    return urls;
  };


  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Header getDrivers={getDrivers} />
      <CardList drivers={drivers} />
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Image 1 (clicked button once):
[image]

Image 2 (clicked button twice):
[image]

Object20Object error:

```
const Header = (props) => {
  const driverYear = useRef();

  const driverYearHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(driverYear);
    const year = driverYear.current.value;
    console.log(typeof year);
    props.getDrivers(year.toString());
  };

  return (
    <header className={classes.header}>
      <Title />
      <form onSubmit={driverYearHandler}>
        {/* <label htmlFor="year">Enter Year:</label> */}
        <input
          type="text"
          id="year"
          ref={driverYear}
          placeholder="Enter Year:"
        />
        <button onClick={props.getDrivers}>Get Drivers</button>
      </form>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Console Error:
[image]
[image]

**UPDATED FETCH CALL**

```
const getDrivers = async (year) => {
    console.log("Running more than once??");
    const url = "https://ergast.com/api/f1/" + year + "/drivers.json";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();

    let driverInfo = [];
    data.MRData.DriverTable.Drivers.map((driver) => {
      driverInfo.push({
        id: driver.code,
        firstName: driver.givenName,
        lastName: driver.familyName,
        wikipedia: driver.url,
        image: null,
      });
    });
    getDriversImgs(driverInfo).then((data) => setDrivers(data));
    console.log("Here is driver info", driverInfo);
  };

  const getDriversImgs = async (driverInfo) => {
    const responses = await Promise.all(
      driverInfo.map((driver) => {
        let wikiPageName = driver.wikipedia.split("/").slice(-1).toString();
        let wiki_url =
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?origin=*&action=query&titles=" +
          wikiPageName +
          "&prop=pageimages&format=json&pithumbsize=500";
        return fetch(wiki_url);
      })
    );
    const urls = await Promise.all(responses.map((r) => r.json())).then(
      (json) => retrievingImgUrl(json)
    );
    return driverInfo.map((item, idx) => {
      return { ...item, image: urls[idx] };
    });
  };

  const retrievingImgUrl = async (data) => {
    const strippingData = data.map((d) => {
      return d.query.pages;
    });
    const urls = strippingData.map((d) => {
      const k = Object.keys(d)[0];
      try {
        return d[k].thumbnail.source;
      } catch {
        return null;
      }
    });
    return urls;
  };
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely happening because of a small misunderstanding with `setState`. You are calling `getDriversImgs()` just after `setDrivers()` is called, but any set state function is asynchronous. It is likely not done setting before you look for the driver's image.

The simplest solution in my opinion will be to not `setDrivers` until you've correlated an image to each driver. You already have all of your `driverInfo` in an array, so iterating through that array and finding the image for the driver should be quite straightforward.

After you've created a `driverInfo` array that *includes* the driver's image, then you can use `setDrivers` which will render it to the DOM.

Comment: Hmm, I would've assumed since they were both Async calls when the event loop would eventually be called the setState would be placed behind the fetch. But now that you mention it the queue would receive the setState call prior to the data. I would have assumed the second setState call would've caused another rerender. I'm going to branch my code and give it a shot thank you!

Comment: You're correct that it would cause another rerender if the drivers state was set. However, with the `drivers` state still showing up as an empty array, there is nothing for it to map over and therefore does nothing to the state. Good luck!

Comment: This is part of the issue with this code, but the actual quirk is because they are using the `drivers` from the App state as a closure, as opposed to either receiving a function argument or accessing it through a class object (this one only works with class-based React components). @pradetto5 are you getting any console errors? My assumption would be the first `getDriversImgs()` fails, which is why you have to click the button again - the second `getDriversImgs` will have the re-rendered App state, which will include the drivers you need to look up. (EDIT: your )

Comment: Yeah I am getting a new error retrieving a ref from my input causing an https://ergast.com/api/f1/[object%20Object]/drivers.json . I am updating my code with the ref component at the bottom. I am currently working on resolving this.

Comment: @pradetto5 Willey's answer is still right - you need to do everything first, _then_ call the setState. My point is simply that the getDriversImg() has an additional bug in that it depends on the `drivers` state as it existed when the App was rendered - so it's always one step behind the actual state when you click on the "getDrivers" button.

Comment: @pachewise Copy that thank you. I was successful at taking Willey's advice and I updated the objects prior to setState call. I can share that code. I will advice if I can resolve the promise bug :) All good learning here thank you again!

Comment: @WilleyOhana aye, I got it working in one call now I just have a fetch bug! Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @pachewise thanks again for the tips! I learned a lot and got the original post fixed. I posted the code at the bottom that resolved it in one render! Is it normal for fetch calls to look this sloppy or am I writing bad code?